# Permission denied to activate python37 in virtualenv in AWS EC2 Linux instance from Jenkins shell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, virtualenv

I am using AWS EC2 Linux instance to run Selenium tests written in python using python37 version, Jenkins shell script has code to activate the python37 in virtualenv before executing tests.

source /home/ec2-user/venv/python37/bin/activate
this gives error :
/tmp/jenkins5176496797782493011.sh: line 4: /home/ec2-user/venv/python37/bin/activate: Permission denied.

But activating the same works from ssh client when logged in as ec2-user.
Is it that jenkins user has no privileges. How cam permissions be granted for jenkins user.

Comment: Why you are not using Jenkins workspace?

Comment: @szogoon Jenkins workspace has the test code checked out from github. Since i need python37, i have created virtualenv.

Comment: @DebanjanB i created python37 version virtualenv to run Selenium tests which needs this version, otheriwse i would use the python27 which is installed by default in AWS EC2 linux instance.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have a feeling that it is a matter of permissions on filesystem

Comment: @szogoon Ofcoarse _matter of permissions on filesystem_ but currently I don't have the required access to any _amazon-ec2_ instance, so can't validate. Hence no answer.

Comment: @DebanjanB ok, and what has Selenium to do in that case?

Comment: @curiousmind can you tell if jenkins user has rights on the folder where you try to do activate?

Comment: @szogoon not related to selenium, when i was new to the problem i added the post and tagged selenium too.

Comment: @szogoon i am not sure of how to give permission to jenkins to the ec2-user where virtual environment is there, since i am new to this. I resolved this issue by making jenkins user as root instead of jenkins and it all works good now.

Comment: try adding jenkins user to ec2-user group and adjust permissions on the folder if needed with chmod